# imprimir en pdf segun el id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdf

tengo la opcion de consultarcartera.php

con el siguiente codigo

```html
<?php
  require '../dbcon.php';
  
  $where = "";
  
  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];
    if(!empty($valor)){
      $where = "WHERE afisaldo LIKE '%$valor'";
    }
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM saldo $where";
   
  $resultado = $connection->query($sql);
  
?>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div class="container py-2">
      <div class="row">
        <br>
        <h2 style="text-align:center">Digite identificación para consultar</h2>
        <br>
          
      </div>
      
      <div class="row pt-2">
      
        
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
          <b>Identificación: </b><input type="text" id="campo" name="campo" />
          <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" />
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <br>
      
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover text-center mt-3">
        <thead bgcolor="4E7D8F" class="texto" style="color:white">
            <tr>
    <th class="text-center">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center">identificación</th>
    <th class="text-center">fecha/Hora de pago </th>
    <th class="text-center">cuota </th>
    <th class="text-center">periodo</th>
    <th class="text-center">Estado</th>
    <th class="text-center">imprimir</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          
          <tbody>
            <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
              <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['idsaldo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['afisaldo']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['fechapago']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['tarifacant']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['periodo']; ?></td>

                 <td><a href="index2.php?pag=verPagos&idsaldo=<?php echo $row['idsaldo']; ?>" ><span class="icono glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>
                  <td><a href="imprimirfacturas.php" ><span class="icono glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span></a></td>
              </tr>

            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

en la opción de imprimirfacturas.php  me da error; como seria el código para que imprima de acuerdo al id que elija para que de el pdf.

```html
<?php
 include 'plantilla.php';
 require '../dbcon.php';

 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM  saldo where idsaldo='".$idsaldo."' ";
 $resultado = $connection->query($query);
 
 $pdf = new PDF();
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 
 $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
 $pdf->Cell(70,6,'HORA DE PAGO',1,0,'C',1);
 $pdf->Cell(20,6,'CEDULA',1,0,'C',1);
 $pdf->Cell(70,6,'MES',1,1,'C',1);
 $pdf->Cell(70,6,'VALOR',1,1,'C',1);

 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
 
 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
 {
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['idsaldo']),1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['fechapago']),1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row['afisaldo'],1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['periodo']),1,1,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['tarifacant']),1,1,'C');
 }
 $pdf->Output("D");
?>
```

Comment: que error te genera ? y no veo la parte en como obtienes $idsaldo,,en imprimirfacturas.php

Comment: si en esa parte no se como formular para que imprima ejemplo todos los datos de la id 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos creo que el error es que no envias dicho id hacia tu archivo php imprimirfacturas.php, en tu archivo principal seria algo asi:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>nombre</td>
<td>Valor</td>
<td>IMPRIMIR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>DIEGO AVILA</td>
<td>10.50</td>
<td><a href="imprimirFactura.php?id=1">Imprimir Factura</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>VALERIA PAREDES</td>
<td>25.50</td>
<td><a href="imprimirFactura.php?id=2">Imprimir Factura</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>FERNANDA PAREDES</td>
<td>100.50</td>
<td><a href="imprimirFactura.php?id=3">Imprimir Factura</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Este es desde donde envio el id, para ello en el hipervinculo agrego algo asi:

```
<a href="imprimirFactura.php?id=3">Imprimir Factura</a>
```

en tu caso podrias reemplarlo por algo como esto:

```
<td><a href="imprimirfacturas.php?id=<?php echo $row['idsaldo']; ?>" ><span class="icono glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span></a></td>
```

ahora en tu php **imprimirfacturas.php** seria algo asi:

```
<?php
include 'plantilla.php';
require '../dbcon.php';

$idsaldo = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM  saldo where idsaldo='".$idsaldo."' ";
$resultado = $connection->query($query);

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(70,6,'HORA DE PAGO',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'CEDULA',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,6,'MES',1,1,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(70,6,'VALOR',1,1,'C',1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['idsaldo']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['fechapago']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row['afisaldo'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['periodo']),1,1,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,utf8_decode($row['tarifacant']),1,1,'C');
}
$pdf->Output("D");
?>
```

si te fijas he agregado una linea que es donde recibo el id que envio desde mi hipervinculo:

```
 $idsaldo = $_GET['id'];
```

espero te sirva de guia y te ayude..suerte...

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya me da el resultado,fue de mucha ayuda su aporte.